Items not showing on time grid as expected
I am using the "Agenda and all TODOs" as my primary view to interact with the agenda. However, I struggle to configure it with org-super-agenda.
My current config is
(setq org-super-agenda-groups
      '(
        (:name "In Progress"
               :todo "INPR" )
        (:name "Todo"
               :todo "TODO" )
        (:name "Waiting"
               :todo "WAIT" )))

which displays the undated TODOs nicely below the time grid, grouped by their state. But the items with a date associated are not displayed correctly:

Enhancing my groups definition by a time-grid selector:
(setq org-super-agenda-groups
      '(
        (:time-grid t)
        (:name "In Progress"
               :todo "INPR" )
        (:name "Todo"
               :todo "TODO" )
        (:name "Waiting"
               :todo "WAIT" )))

fixes the agenda view but makes the "Global list of TODO items" printed ungrouped.
How can I have both, a time-grid with correctly placed icons for icons that have a date and a grouped global TODO list?
An example org file:
* TODO Today's item with time
<2024-06-19 Mi 14:00>
that does not apear on the time-grid, but below
* TODO some non-dated item
which appears correctly


Can you provide a minimal example org file that gives rise to your screenshot?
